# Easiest way to copy large folder to an Azure Disk

Tags: azure

I'm just wondering if there was a straight forward way to copy a large folder onto an Azure Disk.

Naturally, I could spin up a VM, mount the disk and copy things over; but is there a more automated way of doing it? Can we use azcopy? Is there any other az commands that allow us to copy things over to an Azure Disk?

Appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Hi there. I'm trying to understand why you need to do this. Why don't you use a [file share](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share?tabs=azure-portal) instead of a disk? Not sure if it can help there is an [Azure shared disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-shared) where you can attach a managed disk into multiple VM at once. Send us more details what it is exactly your scenario, for example if you need to do it just once or you can copy files to disk many times, maybe you are using a wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly copy files to an Azure Disk that has not been mounted, you would need to mount it and then copy the files.

There are other storage options in Azure that do allow you do to do this. If you use Blob or File storage you can use [AzCopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) to copy files directly to that storage location.